# Digits are getting deleted when splitting a string

Tags: java, split

I have a string from which I need to remove all mentioned punctuations and spaces. My code looks as follows:

```
String s = "s[film] fever(normal) curse;";
String[] spart = s.split("[,/?:;\\[\\]\"{}()\\-_+*=|<>!`~@#$%^&\\s+]");
System.out.println("spart[0]: " + spart[0]);
System.out.println("spart[1]: " + spart[1]);
System.out.println("spart[2]: " + spart[2]);
System.out.println("spart[3]: " + spart[3]);
```

I have a string from which I need to remove all mentioned punctuations and spaces. My code looks as follows:

```
String s = "s[film] fever(normal) curse;";
String[] spart = s.split("[,/?:;\\[\\]\"{}()\\-_+*=|<>!`~@#$%^&\\s+]");
System.out.println("spart[0]: " + spart[0]);
System.out.println("spart[1]: " + spart[1]);
System.out.println("spart[2]: " + spart[2]);
System.out.println("spart[3]: " + spart[3]);
```

But, I am getting some elements which are blank. The output is:

```
spart[0]: s
spart[1]: film
spart[2]:
spart[3]: normal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] spart = s.split("[,/?:;\\[\\]\"{}()\\-_+*=|<>!`~@#$%^&\\s]+");
```

Answer (score 1):

`-` defines a range in regular expressions as used by `String.split` argument so that needs to be escaped

```
String[] part = line.toLowerCase().split("[,/?:;\"{}()\\-_+*=|<>!`~@#$%^&]");
```

Comment: While I want to use whitespace and these symbols to split the string, I am getting issues: some elements are just blank means, "".

The line is as follows:

      String[] spart = s.split("[,/?:;\\[\\]\"{}()\\-_+*=|<>!`~@#$%^&\\s+]");

Comment: Please update the original question if this post does not provide the answer

Answer (score 1):

`-` is a special character in PHP character classes.  For instance, `[a-z]` matches all chars from a to z inclusive.  Note that you've got `)-_` in your regex.